# Curl Scrape content and special characters

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, curl

**I use this curl script for extract content  :**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,$loginpassw);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"UTF-8");
curl_setopt($ch,array(
CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'gzip, deflate',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language: es-ES,en;q=0.5',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
),
));

$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The content for extract have special characters, for example words as "número" in spanish and with "ú" as special characters.

I use enconding UTF-8 in page, the case it´s that when show content, show perfect, don´t show nothing bad, i see the DOM and all perfect, nothing strange.

The problem it´s when for example i want use if or when i want use substr or mb_substr

**For example if the word is "número" and i use :**

```
substr($content,0,6)
mb_substr($content,0,6)
```

Always show &Uacute, but the case is that inside DOM don´t show this, only show when i want show part the content with substr or mb_substr, by this when i want use **"if condition"**, never works :

```
if(substr($content,0,6)=="número")
{
print "yes";
}
```

For me is strange because i put curl with codification utf-8 for extract content, i try also without utf-8 codification in curl, but result it´s the same.

I try many ways for make this and i don´t know why happend really, because in other moment don´t see this problem.

**Thank´s.**

Comment: Please clarify the latter part of the question after "For example if the word is "número" and i use", I'm having trouble understading what the issue is. Is there an XML entity `&Uacute;` in the string? Does `mb_substring()` _not_ work? What are the actual _bytes_ of the input string? `ú` can be represented at least 3 different ways in this context, and copy/pasting rendered text will not necessarily preserve the original format. eg: use `bin2hex($content);` and show us the output of _that_.

Comment: when load the content from curl show perfect the word "número", this word content special character "ú", the problem come when use in the content substr, and it´s indifferent if use mb_substr, because always show &uacute; but the strange is in the dom, in th dom don´t show &uacute and only show when use substr or mb_substr, this is the strange and is the same if use other codification, etc, always happend this

Comment: You need to post some code and example data that we can actually _run_ that demonstrates this issue.